# Saving Array of hashmaps to local database in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage

I am new to Android development.

I am trying to save an array of map in local storage of Android.

Then, the user would get the data, modify the data, and save the array to where it was originally saved.

So for instance, if I have array {Map1, Map2, Map3, Map4, Map5 }
I will save this to local storage, the next time user opens the app, I will retrieve the array, maybe add another map  {Map1, Map2, Map3, Map4, Map5, Map6}, and save it.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two solutions to this problem

1) you can write your owner parser for serializing and parse data, for example, for serializing write each map in the separate line in a file and between each key-value use a delimiter  next for parse data you can create maps by reading lines and fill data by text for each map

2) you can use XML or JSON parser(JSON is the best) then you just use a library for serializing and parse data such as Gson, logan square, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your data to json string and save to Shared Preferences. Whenever you want to get data, you just need parse this json string.